# Backwards axes in numpy.delete

Tags: python, numpy

It seems as though the axis argument in numpy.delete() is backwards from all other axis arguments in both numpy and pandas. Typically, axis=0 refers to columns and axis=1 refers to rows. For example:

```
import numpy as np
mat=np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
# sum columns
np.sum(mat, axis=0)
# sum rows
np.sum(mat, axis=1)
# min of columns
np.min(mat, axis=0)
```

That all works like expected. But if I use numpy.delete, I have to switch:

```
# delete 1st row
np.delete(mat, 0, axis=0)
# delete 1st column
np.delete(mat, 0, axis=1)
```

Has anyone else noticed this? Am I crazy or is this by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by design.  You are specifying the axis from which to delete the given index (or indices).  For example, suppose we have `z` as follows:

```
In [62]: z
Out[62]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

You select different rows of `z` by varying the first index of `z` (i.e. by selecting indices along axis 0):

```
In [63]: z[0, :]
Out[63]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [64]: z[1, :]
Out[64]: array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

So it makes sense that you would also select `axis=0` to delete, say, the row at index 1:

```
In [65]: np.delete(z, 1, axis=0)
Out[65]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Similarly, you use axis 1 (i.e. the second index) to access different columns:

```
In [66]: z[:, 0]
Out[66]: array([ 0,  5, 10])

In [67]: z[:, 3]
Out[67]: array([ 3,  8, 13])
```

and so you use `axis=1` to delete columns:

```
In [68]: np.delete(z, 3, axis=1)
Out[68]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 14]])
```

Don't forget that this generalizes to n-dimensional arrays.  For example, if you have a three-dimensional array `a`, and you want to delete the two-dimensional slice `a[:, :, k]`, you would use `np.delete(a, k, axis=2)`.

Comment: so then why is axis flipped in all of the other commands (i.e. summing across rows is axis=1). Is there a convention for that?

Comment: It is consistent: for a 2-d array, "summing across rows" is actually "summing along axis 1".

Comment: Ohh. Right. Got it. That wasn't how I was thinking about it. Makes a lot more sense now.